# VBA word. HighlightColorIndex of a hyperlink returns 9999999

Tags: vba, hyperlink, ms-word

I'm writing a macro in Word to remove the highlighting from all hyperlinks highlighted with `wdGray25`. The search for all hyperlinks is done by

```
For Each oLink In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
    If oLink.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdGray25 Then
    oLink.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    End If
Next oLink
```

The problem is that highlighting from some hyperlinks highlighted with `wdGray25` is not removed. By examining hyperlinks with Alt+f9 it appears that `wdGray25` highlighting isn't removed from those hyperlinks whose hyperlink/field (revealed only by Alt+f9) isn't highlighted. These hyperlinks seem normally highlighted when hyperlink/field is hidden. For these hyperlinks `Range.HighlightColorIndex` returns 9999999.

How can I rewrite the code so that `wdGray25` hyperlinks are found even though hyperlink/field isn't highlighted?

Comment: Are you sure you're seeing highlighting with the field codes? Or are you seeing field code shading?

Comment: It's highlighting, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

While not a complete answer to the question, the following info might be useful or help to resolve this or a similar issue:
I ran into this issue as well when using "HighlightColorIndex" in VBA. What I find is that it returns 9999999 in case there are two highlight colors in the selection, so that (presumably) the highlight color can't be "determined" as there are multiple highlight colors applied to that selection. In my case this happened when one line of text had multiple highlights, a few words in yellow, and a few in green for example.

Answer (score -1):

### Find and replace specific formatting

You can search for and replace or remove character formatting in your document. For example, you can search for a specific word or phrase and change the font color, or you can search for specific formatting, such as bold or highlight, and change it.

1. On the **Home** tab, in the **Editing** group, choose **Replace**. Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> on your keyboard.

[image: The Replace option is highlighted on the Home tab.]

2. If you don't see the Format button, click More.

   [image: More button]
3. To search for text with specific formatting, type the text in the **Find what** box. To find formatting only, leave the box blank.
4. Click **Format**, and then select the formats that you want to find and replace. For example, to find highlighted text, click **Format > Highlight**; to find bold text, click **Format > Font**, and then in the Find Font dialog box, select **Bold** in the **Font style** list.
5. Click the **Replace with** box, click **Format**, and then select the replacement formats as described in step 4.

> Note: If you also want to replace the text, type the replacement text in the **Replace with** box.

6. To find and replace each instance of the specified formatting, click **Find Next**, and then click **Replace**. To replace all instances of the specified formatting, click **Replace All**.

([Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-and-replace-text-and-other-data-in-a-word-document-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7))

**Also see:** [How to Remove or turn off hyperlinks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/remove-or-turn-off-hyperlinks-027b4e8c-38f8-432c-b57f-6c8b67ebe3b0)

Answer (score -1):

you could exploit the knowledge that those "hidden" hyperlinks have 9999999 as `HighlightColorIndex` property

```
For Each oLink In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
    Select Case oLink.Range.HighlightColorIndex
        Case 9999999, wdGray25
            oLink.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    End Select
Next oLink
```

Comment: @TadejGr, any feedback?