# Macro to remove highlighting from hyperlinks in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm writing a macro to remove all highlight colors in a Word document except wdGray25 (whose HighlightColorIndex equals 15). The problem arises when macro runs into a hyperlink highlighted with wdGray25, whose hyperlink/field isn't highlighted when revealed by Alt+F9. In that case Do While .Execute loop goes into an infinite loop and never exits.

How can I rewrite the code so that .Execute method wouldn't go into an infinite loop? I appreciate your help.

```
color_array = Array("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14")

For Each color_number In color_array

With Selection
.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
With Selection.Find
  .Highlight = True
  .Text = ""

  Do While .Execute
   If Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = color_number Then
      Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
      Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    End If
  Loop

End With
End With
Next
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA word. HighlightColorIndex of a hyperlink returns 9999999](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218280/vba-word-highlightcolorindex-of-a-hyperlink-returns-9999999)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *searching*, we can just *loop** through each `Hyperlink` in the `Hyperlinks` collection:

```
Sub RemoveHighlightFromHyperlinks()
    Dim a As Hyperlink
    For Each a In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
        If a.Range.HighlightColorIndex <> 15 Then a.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdAuto
    Next a
End Sub
```

It loops through all hyperlinks in the document. If `HighlightColorIndex <> 15` then remove `HighlightColorIndex` (by setting to `wdAuto`.)

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [Hyperlinks Collection (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192421(v=office.14).aspx)
- MSDN : [Hyperlink Object (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/hyperlink-object-word)
- MSDN : [Range.HighlightColorIndex Property (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/range-highlightcolorindex-property-word)

Comment: That code won't work for highlighted hyperlinks whose hyperlink/field isn't highlighted when revealed by Alt+F9. HighlightColorIndex for these hyperlinks is 9999999.